# How can you change color and style Settings for Shepherd js

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using Shepherd JS to guide Users through a website with the help of tours.
I already set up different tours, using stepOptions and DefaultstepOptions.

How can I change color settings or style settings of any components of the Shepherd JS Tour, for example change the color of the Next Button to Yellow, etc.?

Comment: https://shepherdjs.dev/docs/tutorial-03-styling.html

Comment: this is the tutorial how to include css classes, but not how to change settings in css for the components and what id etc. to use.

Comment: This doesn't seem related to Java. Why have you tagged [tag:java]? JavaScript and Java are not the same language. The only commonality is that they have the same first 4 letters due to an inconsiderate marketing agreement from the mid 90s between Netscape and Sun.

Comment: It is, you can use Shepherd js in combination with @Clientcallable in java

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you are trying to change.  I would suggest adding custom classes to steps or the tour first.  While setting up the defualtStepOptions for the Tour:

```
defaultStepOptions: {
    classes: 'custom-class',
    scrollTo: { behavior: 'smooth', block: 'center' },
},
```

Then, you can target the class and step modal.

```
.custom-class {
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

Or they do add their own classes.  For instance:

```
.shepherd-footer {
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.shepherd-arrow:before {
    border-left: 2px solid #3c1265;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #3c1265;
}
```

Note the arrow borders are simple and may not be responsive.